# How to parse screenshots in Power Automate

Tags: string, power-automate

I have a bit of a complicated process in Power Automate. I'm trying to parse user uploaded screenshots and categorizing them into different variables. At first, it seemed that an obvious choice would be to build and train the AI Model but the only issue is that the data in the screenshots can vary (i.e. some images will contain more rows, some won't contain the relevant data, and the data can be located in different regions of the screenshot).

Some example of images, which a user can upload, are as follows: (i) [Samsung 1 Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJSbF.jpg), (ii) [Samsung 2 Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7vI5.jpg)  (iii) [iPhone metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hUp3.jpg)

---

My attempt was to perform OCR on the uploaded screenshot and then do string parsing. Therefore, I tried attempting the following flow: [Flow Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mwEt.png) and specifically the substring parsing as:
[Substring parsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rASOt.png)

Basically, I'm performing OCR on the screenshot and then searching for a substring which corresponds to the values that I'm interested in. I'm unsure if this is the best way to do this as it isn't dynamic (i.e. I have to offset the substring index by a certain amount of characters). Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to train a custom Form Processing model to extract the information you need. You can two different collections in your training dataset to have the model be able to recognize both Samsung and iPhone layouts.
All you'll need is 5 samples for each collection and you should be good to go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).